# How to implement a Javascript callback for a multiselect widget in Bokeh

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I am new to both Bokeh and Javascript and I am trying to implement a simple multiselect widget in Bokeh. The idea is simply to display the x and y data on a scatterplot depending on the letter or letters chosen by the user (A, B, C). The graph should be empty before the user selects a choice. The problem lies with the Javascript callback: nothing happens when I select an entry with the MultiSelect widget. The code is below.

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, MultiSelect, Column
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import pandas as pd

data = dict(letter = ['A','A','B','C','B','B','A','C','C','B'], 
x = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3], 
y = ['10','20','10','30','10','40','10','30','10','40'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_source = ColumnDataSource(data)
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(letter = [], x = [], y = []))

plot = figure()
plot.circle('x', 'y', line_width = 2, source = source)

callback = CustomJS(args = {'source': source, 'data_source': data_source},
code = """
var data = data_source
source.data = data[cb_obj.value];
""")

multiselect = MultiSelect(title = 'Choose', value = [], options = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
multiselect.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = Column(multiselect, plot)
show(layout)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. If you'd like to filter data it is generally a good idea to have a "master" data source from which to extract only the required elements as the filtered value changes. I find it easiest to do this using loops (see code below). Also, don't forget to always emit the changes to the source at the end of the callback.

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, MultiSelect, Column

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import pandas as pd

data = dict(letter = ['A','A','B','C','B','B','A','C','C','B'], 
x = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3], 
y = ['10','20','10','30','10','40','10','30','10','40'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_source = ColumnDataSource(data)
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x = [], y = []))

plot = figure()
plot.circle('x', 'y', line_width = 2, source = source)

callback = CustomJS(args = {'source': source, 'data_source': data_source},
code = """
var data = data_source.data;
var s_data = source.data;
var letter = data['letter'];
var select_vals = cb_obj.value;
var x_data = data['x'];
var y_data = data['y'];
var x = s_data['x'];
x.length = 0;
var y = s_data['y'];
y.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < x_data.length; i++) {
    if (select_vals.indexOf(letter[i]) >= 0) {
        x.push(x_data[i]);
        y.push(y_data[i]);
        }
}
source.change.emit();
""")

multiselect = MultiSelect(title = 'Choose', value = [], options = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
multiselect.js_on_change('value', callback)
layout = Column(multiselect, plot)
show(layout)
```

General comment: I - like you - only started using Bokeh recently and I'm a JS novice, too. I found the examples in the Bokeh [user guide](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html), very helpful.

Comment: Thats great, thank you! Only drawback: is it me or the user cannot select multiple letters with this example ? The graph is empty when you select all 3 letters, no ?

Comment: Oops, you're right, sorry, I didn't think of that (I usually work with 'Select' not 'MultiSelect'). I adjusted the code and it should now work with multiple selections, as well.

Comment: You could probably also employ a CDS filter here: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#groupfilter