# Implementing JavaScript callback for checkboxes in bokeh?

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, callback, bokeh

**Short version:** bokeh checkboxes with JS callbacks to plot subsets of a dataframe?

**Longer version:**  The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187774/how-to-implement-a-javascript-callback-for-a-multiselect-widget-in-bokeh) gives a good explanation for multiselect, but I want to do the same thing for checkboxes.  All my data is in one pandas dataframe, and I'm using the checkboxes to select bits of that dataframe for plotting.  I believe that with checkboxes it is something to do with `cb_obj.active` but I'm very unsure how to get it to work.  In particular my plot includes colored rectangles and text, all information for which: position, text, color, is taken from my dataframe.  And I don't know how much plotting must be done in the callback, and how much outside.

As far as I can tell, the callback calls a function to do the actual plotting.

I know I should give a minimal example, but I can't think how to simplify my code enough... so all I really want at the moment is an example of the use of checkboxes, with a JavaScript callback, to plot a subset of a dataframe.  Somebody must have done this, but I haven't found an example yet!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Slider, CheckboxGroup, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, CDSView
from bokeh.models.filters import CustomJSFilter
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.palettes import Category10_10
output_notebook()
```

You can use `CustomJSFilter` to calculate the indice of rows to show:

```
from bokeh.sampledata import iris
source = ColumnDataSource(data=iris.flowers)
species = iris.flowers.species.unique().tolist()
checkboxes = CheckboxGroup(labels=species, active=list(range(len(species))))
fig = figure()
filter =  CustomJSFilter(code="""
let selected = checkboxes.active.map(i=>checkboxes.labels[i]);
let indices = [];
let column = source.data.species;
for(let i=0; i<column.length; i++){
    if(selected.includes(column[i])){
        indices.push(i);
    }
}
return indices;
""", args=dict(checkboxes=checkboxes, source=source))

checkboxes.js_on_change("active", CustomJS(code="source.change.emit();", args=dict(source=source)))

fig.scatter("sepal_length", "sepal_width", 
            color=factor_cmap("species", Category10_10, species),
            source=source, view=CDSView(source=source, filters=[filter]))
show(row(checkboxes, fig))
```

[image]

Comment: This is the exact solution I was looking for!  The combination of CustomJSFillter and CDSView (neither of which I'd come across before) looks like it will do exactly what I want, and very neatly and simply.  Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: One more question: what is the easiest way of adding "select all" and "clear all" callbacks with this approach? Do I need to write separate JS functions for those, or can I simply reference the initial setting somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an adapted version of my answer for MultiSelect that you referred to:

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, CheckboxGroup, Column

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import pandas as pd

data = dict(letter = ['A','A','B','C','B','B','A','C','C','B'], 
x = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3], 
y = ['10','20','10','30','10','40','10','30','10','40'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_source = ColumnDataSource(data)
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x = [], y = []))

plot = figure()
plot.circle('x', 'y', line_width = 2, source = source)

callback = CustomJS(args = {'source': source, 'data_source': data_source},
code = """
var data = data_source.data;
var s_data = source.data;
var letter = data['letter'];
var select_vals = cb_obj.active.map(x => cb_obj.labels[x]);
console.log(select_vals);
var x_data = data['x'];
var y_data = data['y'];
var x = s_data['x'];
x.length = 0;
var y = s_data['y'];
y.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < x_data.length; i++) {
    if (select_vals.indexOf(letter[i]) >= 0) {
        x.push(x_data[i]);
        y.push(y_data[i]);
        }
}
source.change.emit();
console.log("callback completed");
""")

chkbxgrp = CheckboxGroup(labels = ['A', 'B', 'C'], active=[])
chkbxgrp.js_on_change('active', callback)
layout = Column(chkbxgrp, plot)
show(layout)
```

Remarks:

- The callback won't work in Internet Explorer because it uses arrow functions, which IE does not support. If that is an issue, you need
  do the mapping using something other than arrow functions
- as user bigreddot commented in the answer you referred to, this could also be done using CDSView using a custom Filter, as GroupFilter does not support multiple values

Comment: Thank you very much - in fact HYRY's answer below does just that, and it seems perfect for my purpose.  Bokeh is wonderful, but (at least for me, as a beginner) hard to find the right combination of elements to get the effect I want.

Comment: @bexi - How does the update goes? I tried your code above but you are not sending the new x & y back...??