# How to write Javascript code for part of Bokeh callback filter, so that I can filter by both number and categories?

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm building a Bokeh visualisation and have got stuck with Javascript. I've adjusted some JS code to work with a slider, and I also want to additionally filter these results by category with a checkbox.

I've been trying to get what I've got (simplified version below) to work with other code I've found on [the likes of this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526738/implementing-javascript-callback-for-checkboxes-in-bokeh), but I have no idea how to expand on it after the first JS for loop. I'd include what I've been drafting but frankly it's a nonsensical mess of garbage.

```
from bokeh.models import Slider, CustomJSFilter, CDSView, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup
from bokeh.layouts import column, layout

data = dict(Flights=[97, 34, 23, 6, 26, 97, 21, 92, 73, 10, 92, 14, 77, 4, 25, 48, 26, 39, 93],
            Not_Cancelled=[87, 63, 56, 38, 57, 63, 73, 56, 30, 23, 66, 47, 76, 15, 80, 78, 69, 87, 28],
            OnTime_Arrivals=[21, 65, 86, 39, 32, 62, 46, 51, 17, 79, 64, 43, 54, 50, 47, 63, 54, 84, 79],
            Category = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
Category_dict = dict(Cat = ['A','B','C'])
MinFlights = Slider(start=0, value=50, end=100, step=1)
MinFlights.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
   source.change.emit()
"""))
checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels= list(Category_dict["Cat"]), active = [1])
checkbox_group.js_on_change("active", CustomJS(code="source.change.emit();", args=dict(source=source)))

custom_filter = CustomJSFilter(args=dict(source=source, MinFlights=MinFlights), code='''
    var indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++){
        if (source.data['Flights'][i] > MinFlights.value){
            indices.push(true);
        } else {
            indices.push(false);}}
    return indices;
''')
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[custom_filter])

p = figure()
p.circle('OnTime_Arrivals', 'Not_Cancelled', source=source, view=view, size=20)

inputs = column(MinFlights, checkbox_group, width=200)
show(layout([[inputs,p]]))
```

Could someone please help me out? All I need is some code demonstrating how it works and I can adapt the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no bokeh expert, but it appears to me that your issue can be solved by using a "BooleanFilter".

Advantage: You can write python code using booleanFilter and don't have to worry about JS

For Example I'd something like this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from bokeh.models import BooleanFilter,ColumnDataSource,CDSView

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df["bools"]=np.where((df.Flights > 10)&(df.Category=="A"),True,False)
view = CDSView(source=ColumnDataSource(df), filters=[BooleanFilter(bools)])
```

Comment: Oh! Does using a BooleanFilter and not worrying about the JS require using the Bokeh server? I thought that if you're not using the Bokeh server any change caused by what viewers do in the browser needs to be handled by JS (as browsers know nothing about Python). Or do I have the wrong idea?

Comment: BooleanFilter  in itself doesn't require Bokeh server, but if you're generating interactive plots, then the server is required ( if you're not using JS that is). You have it right. If you're not able to write JS, then Bokeh server may be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

One way to realize it is to add `checkbox_group=checkbox_group, categories=categories` to your `CustomJSFilter` callback so it knows the current categories selection. Then you add a second filtering step on `indices` to eventually return the `selected` array in your callback (works for Bokeh v 1.3.0).

```
from bokeh.models import Slider, CustomJSFilter, CDSView, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, CheckboxGroup, Column, Row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

data = dict(Flights=[97, 34, 23, 6, 26, 97, 21, 92, 73, 10, 92, 14, 77, 4, 25, 48, 26, 39, 93],
            Not_Cancelled=[87, 63, 56, 38, 57, 63, 73, 56, 30, 23, 66, 47, 76, 15, 80, 78, 69, 87, 28],
            OnTime_Arrivals=[21, 65, 86, 39, 32, 62, 46, 51, 17, 79, 64, 43, 54, 50, 47, 63, 54, 84, 79],
            Category = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

categories = ['A','B','C']

MinFlights = Slider(start=0, value=50, end=100, step=1)
MinFlights.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
   source.change.emit()
"""))

checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels= categories, active = [0, 1, 2])
checkbox_group.js_on_change("active", CustomJS(code="source.change.emit();", args=dict(source=source)))

custom_filter = CustomJSFilter(args=dict(source=source, MinFlights=MinFlights, checkbox_group=checkbox_group, categories=categories), code='''
    var indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++){
        if (source.data['Flights'][i] > MinFlights.value){
            indices.push(true);
        } else {
            indices.push(false);}}

    selected = []
    for (i in indices) {
        let selected_categories = checkbox_group.active.map((i) => categories[i])
        console.log(selected_categories)
        console.log(i, indices[i], source.data['Category'][i], selected_categories.includes(source.data['Category'][i]))
        if(indices[i] && selected_categories.includes(source.data['Category'][i])) {
            selected.push(true)
        }
        else {
            selected.push(false)
        }
    }
    return selected;
''')
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[custom_filter])

p = figure()
p.circle('OnTime_Arrivals', 'Not_Cancelled', source=source, view=view, size=20)

inputs = Column(MinFlights, checkbox_group, width=200)
show(Row(inputs, p))
```

[image]

Comment: [@Chris Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4107349/chris-dixon) Does this post answer your question? If yes vote up and accept this answer.